# jqgrid select list column with formatter option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid JS v5.3.2. 
I have a key/value pair list like this on the server

```
key|value
23|abc
12|bdc
100|fghe
```

Right now, I'm using two columns to show/edit this list like below:
...

```
{
    label: 'thelist',
    name: 'key',
    hidden: true,
    editable: true,
    editrules: {
        edithidden: true
    },
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        dataUrl: function () {
            return "getlisthtmlfromserverURL";
        }
    }
},
{
    label: 'thelist',
    name: 'value',
    width: 150
},
```

...

I have tried formatter: 'select' on above first column to eliminate the need of second column (/having two jqgrid columns serving one data field), but it doesn't show the text/value of the select. My guess is that the jqgrid load (remote) select content during edit time, so there is nothing to show. The question is how can I use one column in colModel to show and edit a data field of above list? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you haven't read [the docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#formatter-select) , so you should know that the formatter of type select does not support dataUrl option - it support only string and object values - i.e the values should be predefined, before they come to grid.

In order to have one field you should first get the key/value before to construct the grid and pass it as as value parameter in formatoptions.

```
{
    name:'key', 
    formatter:'select', 
    formatoptions : {value:"23:abc;12:bdc;100:fghe"},
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        value:"23:abc;12:bdc;100:fghe"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In case of custom option to preload the selects it is not so difficult. You should just do

```
$.ajax({
    url : "url_to get_select(s)",
    success : functon(....) {
        // build your select string here 
        // call the jqGrid with that string.
        $(...).jqGrid({...});
    }
})
```

Comment: Thx Tony. I was expecting, for a great plug-in as jqGrid, is it possible to automate such a "preload" by jqgrid framework other than the user providing custom code, considering I have dozens key/value list (if not hundreds)? after all, once formatter is defined and the dataUrl provided, the jqGrid should have the ability to load the lists just as loading the grid content. the user may be able to choice aggressive loading or lazily if performance is concerned.

Comment: To explain simple - dataUrl is nothing more as additional ajax to get the key/value - this mean, that these ajax calls should be loaded before the data, since the grid does not know what for data will be. If we make this logic the speed of grid will be incredible slow down, since we should first to load the key/values of selects and then to load the data, which in our opinion is not acceptable

Comment: Sure, Tony. My suggestion is give the user the option to chose between preload and custom code for select-list column.

Comment: The grid has too many options and adding new one will make it like mastodon. Please look at my updated answer